# Ttitle showing twice in Category Archives Pages

Tags: css, wordpress

Title showing Twice in a few posts on Category Archives. I tried several ways but unable to find the right solution.

URL - https://www.radracquets.com/review-guides/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add more details on what you have tried so far.

Comment: _“I tried several ways but unable to find the right solution.”_ - please find (out) how to ask a halfway proper question first of all - [ask].

Comment: @Vel yes only in that, I removed that. What about the rest of the pages?

Comment: can you post your `review-guides` code?. I mean archive.php file code?

Comment: @Vel you can check this "Best Tennis Racquets for Tennis Elbow" it's not added in post content but still the title shows twice in archive pages.

Comment: @vel it says 5258 characters, too long to post the code

Comment: Here it is https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UK0aW1flxgL_nDJSwowEOwse2j-TkTNivaiwgVfBe54/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Add this css in archive.php file.

```
<style>
     .thrv_wrapper.thrv_heading,.thrv_wrapper.thrv_text_element{
        display: none;
      }
</style>
```

Comment: Added by adding !important; as well, but not worked.

Comment: where you added?. I cannot see in page-source view-source:https://www.radracquets.com/review-guides/

Comment: can you check if it is correct? radracquets.com/wp-content/themes/focusblog/style.css

Comment: Checked but not wroking. https://www.radracquets.com/review-guides/

Comment: Funtions.php code - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lTE7-jhQS3xFTp3NLIIxFF94aMKK9J9AwQgW9b9Rycs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry I don't get you

Comment: where you include this css file `radracquets.com/wp-content/themes/focusblog/style.css` in your theme

Comment: This stlyle.css loading from cache. add this css on some other file.

Comment: can I add this in custom .css?

Comment: I added in custom.css. The current issue is solved but the homepage and a few other pages are collapsed. H1 and other texts are disappeared from the home page

Comment: I added the below CSS and it worked

.archive .thrv_heading{
 display: none!important;}

Comment: Great. Glad to help you